# How to connect to AWS OpenSearch using Spring Boot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I'm trying to add AWS OpenSearch to my project, which is based on Spring Boot 3.

I already created AWS OpenSearch, and then I want to connect from Spring Boot application to AWS OpenSearch. However, It is very hard to find a tutorial for doing that whereas there are lots of tutorials to know about AWS OpenSearch itself.

It may be very silly question, but is there someone who can give me the guidance website to connect to AWS OpenSearch from Spring Boot 3?

I've tried to google to find out how to connect to the AWS OpenSearch from Spring Boot 3, but I couldn't find a proper one. I'd like to want to find some documents or guidances to do that.